# Could not find class android.opengl.EGLConfig[] in native WebRTC

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, egl

I have an error log while I am trying to use WebRTC native codes on my android application.

I think the bold typed errors from log is showing this line in the native file [EglBase.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/trunk/talk/+/master/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/EglBase.java) of WebRTC

> EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];

I am having no trouble calling first time my app starts. When I try right after first one, one of these three situations occur: app crashes, quits the activity silently, or just shows the loopback stream but not showing the remote stream.

**My question is**: Why do you think these errors occur and can you suggest a way to fix them?

My log:

> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext, referenced from method org.webrtc.VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceCreated
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1097: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglGetCurrentContext ()Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
> - D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/btt.androidrtc/lib/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so 0x41580758
> - D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/btt.androidrtc/lib/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so 0x41580758
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 106 (EGL_NO_CONTEXT) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0000
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;)
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0003
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 107 (EGL_NO_DISPLAY) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;)
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;)
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLConfig;)
> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglCreateContext, referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.createEglContext
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1092: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglCreateContext (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;Landroid/opengl/EGLConfig;Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;[II)Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0007
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0023
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: **unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;)**
> - E/dalvikvm: **Could not find class 'android.opengl.EGLConfig[]', referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.getEglConfig**
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: **unable to resolve new-array 4827 ([Landroid/opengl/EGLConfig;) in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;**
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x23 at 0x0026
> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglGetDisplay, referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.getEglDisplay
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1098: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglGetDisplay (I)Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0001
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0027
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;)
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglDestroyContext, referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.release
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1095: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglDestroyContext (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;)Z
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000d
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0002
> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglQuerySurface, referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.surfaceHeight
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1101: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglQuerySurface (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;Landroid/opengl/EGLSurface;I[II)Z
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
> - I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglQuerySurface, referenced from method org.webrtc.EglBase.surfaceWidth
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1101: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglQuerySurface (Landroid/opengl/EGLDisplay;Landroid/opengl/EGLSurface;I[II)Z
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
> - W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 108 (EGL_NO_SURFACE) in Landroid/opengl/EGL14;
> - D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006a at 0x08 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.checkIsNotReleased
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006a at 0x0b in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.createEglContext
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006c at 0x42 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.createSurfaceInternal
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006b at 0x05 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.getEglDisplay
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006c at 0x56 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.createPbufferSurface
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006c at 0x04 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.detachCurrent
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006a at 0x06 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.detachCurrent
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006a at 0x18 in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.release
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006b at 0x1c in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.release
> - I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x006c at 0x0d in Lorg/webrtc/EglBase;.releaseSurface
> - I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglBase: SDK version: 16
> - I/org.webrtc.Logging: VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.setView
> - I/org.webrtc.Logging: VideoRendererGui: YuvImageRenderer.Create id: 0
> - I/org.webrtc.Logging: Vi> * I/CONVERSATION: new instance created with id: 1097893216 and taskID: 5

My dependencies:

- io.pristine:libjingle:10111 //current latest version
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0

Comment: I am in the same boat trying to resolve this since a week now. Did you find a solution? Can you please share the solution if possible?